# Not receiving any sign up mail, when user registers... Both admin & user

Tags: user-registration, email, email-verification

Not receiving any sign up mail, when user registers... Both admin & user .....

https://newsangels.com/manra?action=register

But user is registered, but no email sending...

**However, If I try signup using the theme signup form which is at the top of site, it works then**

I'm using following code as mu-plugin:
Is it causing the issue?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Functions
Description: Custom functions.php coding
Author: UsmanSwift
Version: 1.0

*/
   
#RankMaths#
add_filter( "rank_math/snippet/rich_snippet_article_entity", function( $entity ) {
    if ( in_category('News') ) {
    $entity['@type'] = 'NewsArticle';
}
 return $entity;
});

#Crunchify Remove Head Extra Codes

// *********** Crunchify Tips - Clean up WordPress Header START ******* //
function crunchify_remove_version() {
    return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator', 'crunchify_remove_version');
 
remove_action('wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links', 10);
remove_action('template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0);
 
remove_action ('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');
 
function crunchify_cleanup_query_string( $src ){ 
    $parts = explode( '?', $src ); 
    return $parts[0]; 
} 
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'crunchify_cleanup_query_string', 15, 1 ); 
// ******************** Clean up WordPress Header END ********************** //

#Crunchify Remove Comments and WP Bar

add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'esc_html' );  // remove html from comemnt
 
//add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); // disable admin bar

//Author - Show Own Posts
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;
 
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;
 
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');

//Author - Submit For Review
//function remove_author_publish_posts(){

    // $wp_roles is an instance of WP_Roles.
//    global $wp_roles;
 //   $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'publish_posts' );
//}

//add_action( 'init', 'remove_author_publish_posts' );

//Author - Prevent Own Posts Deletion
//function wpb_change_author_role(){
//    global $wp_roles;
//    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'delete_posts' );
//    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'delete_published_posts' );
 
//}
//add_action('init', 'wpb_change_author_role');

// Revert (Author - Prevent Own Posts Deletion)

//Remove Above Code and Add This

//function wpb_change_author_role(){
//    global $wp_roles;
//    $wp_roles->add_cap( 'author', 'delete_posts' );
//    $wp_roles->add_cap( 'author', 'delete_published_posts' );
// 
//}
//add_action('init', 'wpb_change_author_role');


// Load Essential Fonts Awesome

add_filter( 'infophilic_fontawesome_essentials', 'infophilic_fontawesome_essentials' );
function infophilic_fontawesome_essentials()
{
   return true;
}

// Removing Emojis

//add_action( 'init', 'infophilic_disable_wp_emojicons' );
//function infophilic_disable_wp_emojicons() 
//{ 
    // all actions related to emojis

//    remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
//    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
//    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
//    remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
//    remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
//    remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
//    remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
//}

// Remove Devicepx script 

function jeherve_dequeue_devicepx() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'devicepx' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jeherve_dequeue_devicepx' );

// Remove WP embed script

function infophilic_stop_loading_wp_embed() {
   if (!is_admin()) {
      wp_deregister_script('wp-embed');
}
}
add_action('init', 'infophilic_stop_loading_wp_embed');

// Preload Newspaper fonts for responsive theme (main theme)

function dns_prefetch_responsive() {
    
    echo "<link href='https://newsangels.com/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/images/icons/newspaper.woff?19' rel='preload' as='font' type='font/woff' crossorigin>";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'dns_prefetch_responsive', 0 );

/**
 * Disable access to Media Images for Author
 */
function my_authored_content($query) {

//get current user info to see if they are allowed to access ANY posts and pages
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// set current user to $is_user
$is_user = $current_user->user_login;

//if is admin or 'is_user' does not equal #username
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){
    //if in the admin panel
    if($query->is_admin) {

        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);

    }
    return $query;
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_authored_content');

//Hide Menu Options in Admin Section
//add_action('admin_menu','wf_cli_remove_admin_menu');
//function wf_cli_remove_admin_menu()
//{
//    remove_menu_page('index.php');
//    remove_menu_page('separator1');
//    remove_menu_page('separator2');
//    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
//    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=tdb_templates');
//    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
//}

        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wf_cli_remove_admin_menu' );
        function wf_cli_remove_admin_menu() {
            $wf_user    = wp_get_current_user();
            $wf_roles   = array( 'contributor', 'author' );
            if( array_intersect( $wf_roles, $wf_user->roles ) ) :
                remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
                remove_menu_page( 'separator1' );
                remove_menu_page( 'separator2' );
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
                remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=tdb_templates' );
                remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
            endif;
        }

/**
 * This function will connect wp_mail to your authenticated
 * SMTP server. Values are constants set in wp-config.php
 */
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->Port       = SMTP_PORT;
    $phpmailer->Username   = SMTP_USER;
    $phpmailer->Password   = SMTP_PASS;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->From       = SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName   = SMTP_NAME;
}


//Remove Comments from Admin bar
function my_admin_bar_render() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_admin_bar_render' );

?>
```

Comment: This only shows the front-end form, not how the registrations are handled by PHP / WP. It's not possible to offer suggestions without seeing that backend part also.

Comment: How can I find backend code